# nodejs express cannot get the url and data from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

Writing simple app to fetch data from nodejs server.

but it seems not to get the file in browser as well as in POSTMAN. I have tried multiple times to check the urls but to no avail.

here are my files:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('./Routes/routes');

const hostname = "localhost";
const port = "8055";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
    });

    app.use('/', router);
    app.listen(port,hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on http://${hostname}:${port}');
    })
```

**routes.js**

```
    const express = require('express')

var CityListController = require('../Controllers/City')
var RestaurantCityController = require('../Controllers/Restaurants')
var MenuController = require('../Controllers/Menu')


const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getCityList',CityListController.getCityList);
router.get('/getRestaurantsByCity/:cityname', RestaurantCityController.getRestaurantsByCity);
router.get('/getMenu', MenuController.getMenu);

module.exports = router;
```

**Menu.js**

```
const mealtypes = require('../Models/menu.json');

exports.getMenu = (req, res) => {
const resultname = mealtypes.map(items => items.name)

res.status(200).json({
    message: "widgets data fetched successfully",
    name : resultname
 
   })
 }
```

**menu.json**  goes like this

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Breakfast",
    "content": "Start your day with exclusive breakfast options",
    "image": "assets/breakfast.png"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Lunch",
    "content": "Start your day with exclusive breakfast options",
    "image": "assets/lunch.png"
}
 ]
```

error is
**Cannot GET /getMenu**

not sure where the error is because it is a simple route.. not sure what is missing.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the CORS? It seems the router is not getting registered. Also, you don't need to use `bodyParser.json()` as it will be auto done by express v4+.

Comment: try removing extra slash (/) in router.js file from /getMenu, it should be "getMenu"

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work with http://localhost:8055/getMenu. I copied your code and works for me [link to repo](https://github.com/dirk005/test).

```js
{
    "message": "widgets data fetched successfully",
    "name": [
        "Breakfast",
        "Lunch"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `Cannot GET /` arises from trying to visit `http://localhost:8055`

- It is generated because there is no route for the root directory `http://localhost:8055/` using the path `/` in express.
- The *is* a route for `http://localhost:8055/getMenu` which works fine.

**Test code**

```
const express = require('express');

const getMenu = (req,res) => res.status(200).json({ test_data: "test_data"});
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/getMenu', getMenu);

const hostname = "localhost";
const port = "8055";

const app = express();
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(port,hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there has been a technical error.

It is working fine now. I just restarted nodemon app.js.

and it is working now. Been trying this whole time to get the url fixed.

thanks for your help all